# Agent not appears in UI(GCP storage transfer service)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

After installing the agent on my GCP VM, agent not appears in UI, so I cannot perform transfer jobs, container successfully running. Some logs from ***agent.INFO***

```
I0119 15:00:56.534870       1 prodlayer.go:217] layer successfully set to NO_LAYER with source DEFAULT
I0119 15:00:56.536071       1 memory.go:91] Memory ratio may not be optimal. In a typical server,  you have 2147483648 bytes memory not being used.
I0119 15:01:01.233876       1 handler.go:46] TaskletHandler initialized to delete at most 1000 objects in parallel:
I0119 15:01:01.233896       1 handler.go:49] TaskletHandler initialized with delete-files: 64
I0119 15:01:01.234036       1 handler.go:145] TaskletHandler initialized with copy-files: &{0xc0009da480 10800000000000}
I0119 15:01:01.234071       1 handler.go:62] TaskletHandler initialized to process at most 16 list outputs in parallel:
I0119 15:01:56.536419       9 cpuutilization.go:86] Last minute's CPU utilization: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deep investigation, I assume that this is probably a bug, agent is successfully installed and ready to use indeed. To view the agent in UI I just make a workaround - I have run the transfer job and agent successfully appears in GCP console.